# Multiline text to fit parent container in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a flexbox layout and am trying to get the text in a specific div to be resized to fit that div.

So for example, if I have code as follows:

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
   <div style={{flex: 1}}>
      A really, really, really, really long phrase here that will fit this div, and may wrap onto multiple lines if necessary. In this case it should fill half of the available space as the other div will cover the other half of the space.
   </div>
   <div style={{flex: 1}}>
      Some other text
   </div>
</div>
```

In reality, the text will be pulled from a database, so will be dynamic in length.

How can I get the text in the first div to automatically adjust to fit the entire div?

**Clarification:** the div should stay a fixed size and only the text should be downsized to fit the div rather than overflowing the div.

**Update**

I have also posted a [more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305921/react-textfit-not-fitting-text-correctly-in-multi-mode) about a specific module called *react-textfit* not working the way I would expect it to work.

Comment: By 'the text should be downsized', do you mean it should have smaller font-size till it'll fit?

Comment: We must be missing some information, because I recreated both your questions, and I managed it both time: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgKrZm and https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hawking-un425

Comment: @ChrisR, There must have been something I was missing before too, because now it seems to be working. However, one more problem remains.  I am using flex in the above example partly to give equal space to the elements, but also to easily vertical and horizontal align. Using your code I have been able to horizontally center, but not vertically center. Do you have any suggestions for this. See fork of your code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-flower-7s7uu

Comment: @ChrisR I've also tracked down a big part of my problem. The problem is when the text is dynamically retrieved then it does not auto-fit.

Comment: @kojow7 Please create a new question and tag me in it, I can take a look. Any of those answers here are ok ? Is this question still valid ?

Comment: @kojow7 Does the div you want to fit the text into have a fixed width, height, or both?  Do you wish to change the font size of the text, or to make the text wrap to the next line (and possibly make the div taller)?

Answer (score 5):

Here is some code that should do what you are asking.

```
let size_div = document.querySelector("#font_size");
let div = document.querySelector("#fixed");

while (div.scrollHeight > div.clientHeight) {
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(div, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  let fontSize = parseFloat(style);

  if (fontSize <= 1) {
    break;
  }

  div.style.fontSize = "" + (fontSize - 1) + "px";
  size_div.innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + div.style.fontSize;
}
```

[image]
[image]

You can try it out here: 
https://codepen.io/lowtex/pen/xNawEO

Comment: @kojow7 Does this answer your question?

Comment: mm a long string would not break, and overflow instead. and way to work around that?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply hard code the size to 50 %

```
<div style="display:flex">
  <div style="width:50%;background:lightgrey;">
    A really, really, really, really long phrase here that will fit this div, and may wrap onto multiple lines if necessary. In this case it should fill half of the available space as the other div will cover the other half of the space.
  </div>
  <div style="width:50%;background:lightblue;">
    Some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not a reactJs user but I have worked with CSS flex

you can set height of the container to auto so that it changes as we get the content. Also, you should set min-height and `max-height` properties in css so that if content is less that given length, it appears on `min-height` and if the content is way to big, it does not exceed the given container height.

In order to disallow content from getting out of the box, you can use `overflow:hidden`. this will keep the content from getting out of the box.

Hope this gives some help with how you want to proceed.

Comment: I am wanting the size of the div to stay fixed, but the text size to grow or shrink to fit that div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
<div
    style={{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "lightGrey",
    wordBreak: "break-word"
    }}
>
    A really, really, really, really long phrase here that will fit this
    div, and may wrap onto multiple lines if necessary. In this case it
    should fill half of the available space as the other div will cover
    the other half of the space.
</div>
<div style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "lightBlue" }}>
    Some other text
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't resize the text.