# react-textfit not fitting text correctly in multi mode

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the [react-textfit](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-textfit) module with multi-line support. However, my text is overflowing the parent div rather than fitting neatly inside.

An excerpt of my code:

```
return(
    <div style={{margin: '10px', border: 'solid black 2px', width: '200px', height: '80px'}}>
        <Textfit mode="multi">
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
        </Textfit>
    </div>
)
```

What I am seeing:

[image]

The text does auto-fit for `single` mode and shows correctly on a single line. However, when I switch it to `multi` mode, it is behaving as if I am not even using the `<Textfit>` module.

Additional note: while the above text is hard-coded, the actual text will be dynamically pulled from a database.

Question:

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this so that the text fits inside of the div container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline text to fit parent container in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301566/multiline-text-to-fit-parent-container-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the `Textfit` know the height of the parent div with:  `<Textfit mode="multi" style={{height: '100%'}}>` or you can make the parent `div` a `display: flex`.

I'm not exactly sure of how `Textfit` works under the hood but this works fine in almost every scenarios.

Here's a small [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6nxntt) to illustrate.

Let me know if this doesn't do exactly what you want! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fit it in a parent div, you need to tell the Textfit component how big the height is going to be.

```
  return(
<div style={{margin: '10px', border: 'solid black 2px', width: '200px', height: '80px'}}>
    <Textfit mode="multi" style={{height: '80px'}}>
        The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    </Textfit>
</div>
```

)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The component should have a fixed width and height to be able to handle auto fitting the text.

Comment: Adding a height to the Texfit component does not make a difference. Also, the specs say that Textfit will fit the text to the parent component, so it doesn't make sense to me why you would need to specify a height for the Textfit component itself.